# Calling a specific range of rows in a python database with specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I'm looking to select a certain range of rows [25:100] and a certain list of indexed columns [1,3,6] from a python pandas dataframe using the subscript option.

So far I am using the following

```
 df[25:100][[1, 3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.iloc` (“location by integer”) attribute:

```
df.iloc[25:100, [1, 3, 6]]
```

Note that `25:100` select zero-based numbered rows from 25 (inclusive) to 100 (exclusive). If you want to select the row 100, too, use `25:101` instead.

Comment: So theres no way to call an indexed column using the subscript option?

Comment: If you see `][` in your expression (mainly in the left-hand side of the assignment), you may go into problems. Don't think about it and use consistently only `.loc` and `.iloc`.

Answer (score 0):

The `df.loc` will do the task. However, for simple copies, there are other ways.

### Import pandas

```
>>> import pandas as pd
```

### Create dataframe

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": ["a", "b", "c"]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

### Copy rows from one column only

```
>>> df1 = df["B"][1:]
>>> df1
1    b
2    c
Name: B, dtype: object
```

### Copy rows from more than one row

```
>>> df2 = df[["A","B"]][1:]
>>> df2
   A  B
1  2  b
2  3  c
```

### Copy specific rows and columns (`df.loc`)

```
>>> df3 = df.loc[[0,2] , ["A", "B"]]
>>> df3
   A  B
0  1  a
2  3  c
>>>
```